# Android- Share on facebook using SDK 4.6.0

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook share status in my app.
After registering my app in facebook developer ,
I add this in my manifest:

```
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <provider
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider109...."
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

and this code in my `MainActivity`:

```
/** Open FB Share  */
public static void FBShare(Context ctx) {
    Log.i("FBShare", "Clicked");
    // TODO Check this
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(ctx);
        ShareDialog shareDialog =new ShareDialog((Activity) ctx);
         callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        //shareDialog =
    final String LOG_TAG="FBShare";
    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "cancel");
        }
    });

    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Hello")
                .setContentDescription("Description")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
                .build();
        shareDialog.show((Activity) ctx, content);
    }

}
```

and this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("onActivityResult", "result " + ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class));

}
```

But when pressing the "share" button in my app, it opens facebook app but not sharing any status.

What am I doing wrong ?

beast regurds